How i can to set array objects in zustand?
type Snake = {
    data: {
        id: string;
        isPicked: boolean;
        color: string;
    }[],
    setIspicked:(prevstate:{id:string, isPicked:boolean, color:string}, isPicked:boolean) => void
}

  export const useSnake = create<Snake>((set) => ({
    data:[
        {id:'1', isPicked:false, color:''},            
        {id:'2', isPicked:false, color:''},
        {id:'3', isPicked:false, color:''},
        {id:'4', isPicked:false, color:''},            
        {id:'5', isPicked:false, color:''},
        {id:'6', isPicked:false, color:''},
        {id:'7', isPicked:false, color:''},            
        {id:'8', isPicked:false, color:''},
        {id:'9', isPicked:false, color:''},
        {id:'10', isPicked:false, color:''},            
        {id:'11', isPicked:false, color:''},
        {id:'12', isPicked:false, color:''},
        {id:'13', isPicked:false, color:''},
        {id:'14', isPicked:false, color:''},            
        {id:'15', isPicked:false, color:''},
        {id:'16', isPicked:false, color:''}
    ],

    setIspicked:(prevstate:{id:string, isPicked:boolean, color:string}, Bool:boolean) => {
        
    }
  }))

i want to find object === prevstate from setIspicked props and update his isPicked from isPicked props but i dont know how use map inside set()

setIspicked:(prevstate:{id:string, isPicked:boolean, color:string}, Bool:boolean) => {
    set(state => ({data: state.data.map(res => res === prevstate? {id:prevstate.id, isPicked:Bool, color:prevstate.color}:res)}))
}


It's not clear to me whether this is the answer to your question - in this case, please edit the answer and say so - or a clarification to your question - in this case, please edit the question itself.
